# Dojo 1.4 Framework OnKeyPress Event does not handle ENTER for newer Firefox

Tags: firefox, dojo

I am developing an old system using Dojo 1.4. It was all working on Firefox version 24, I believe starting in version 36 the onkeypress event no longer capture the ENTER event.

Is there any reason why Firefox no longer throws onkeypress event on ENTER key?

Comment: It's definitely not a problem with Firefox. We need an example of your Dojo code, show how to reproduce your problem. https://jsfiddle.net/krupzg20/